# Simultaneous equations in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, equation

I am not 100% sure the right term is simultaneous equation. It could also be function group.

My problem is that I am trying to solve equations with two or more unknowns with LINQ.

For example:

```
x + y = 10
3x + 5y = 30
```

(or with x, y and z etc.)

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find any info regarding this kind of mathematical questions in LINQ.

Comment: I fail to see an actual question in this.

Comment: Why do you think you would be able to do this with LINQ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ. The purpose of LINQ is not solving mathematical equations.

Comment: I'm not sure you can (or should) hit every nail with the Linq hammer.

Comment: I was told to look for help with LINQ in my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try looking at the [Math.NET Linq Algebra](http://linqalgebra.mathdotnet.com/) library. It can do what you are asking.

Comment: It is, though LINQ really does have nothing to do with math or algebra lol...but someone made a library for it

Comment: Really interesting. But I can't find any documentation or sample.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the library although judging by the original post's comments I would get better results with something else.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn - You are right. There isn't much docs on it other then a few unit tests.

Comment: @bloodleh - I don't know what you are trying to do, but if you just need to parse math expressions, try looking at [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)